# Where do I centrally configure the access credentials for the fog gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, fog

I don't want to place it in the code in situ where it is to be used; how/where should it be defined normally?

I want the connection to be accessible from all over the application, as follows:

```
connection = Fog::Storage.new({
  :provider                 => 'AWS',
  :aws_secret_access_key    => YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  :aws_access_key_id        => YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID
})
```

(from http://fog.io/1.0.0/about/getting_started.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could set up a constant in an initializer.

**config/initializers/fog.rb**

```
FOG_CONNECTION = Fog::Storage.new({
  :provider                 => 'AWS',
  :aws_secret_access_key    => YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  :aws_access_key_id        => YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID
})
```

This will then be available within your application as `FOG_CONNECTION.directories.get(...)`.

Comment: what is the implication of setting it like this? Will the connection be re-used?